# How to execute Bootstrap on the training dataset?

Tags: r, training-data

I'm trying to perform bootstrap on the training dataset so I can compare the coefficients and the std estimated with the linear model results, but every time I get the same error.

```
library(boot)

set.seed(1)

train = sample(dim(data)[1], dim(data)[1]*0.7, replace = FALSE)
df <- data[train,]

data <- data %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(Research, LOR, SOP, UniRatings), as.factor)

df <- data[train,]

# discrete variables to dummy 
df <- df %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(df$Research, df$LOR, df$SOP, df$UniRatings), as.factor)


get_model <- function(data, index){
  boot_data <- data[index,]
  boot_model <- glm(Admit ~ GRE + TOEFL + CGPA + LOR + Research, data = boot_data)  
  return (boot_model$coefficients)
}

boot_model <- boot(data = df, statistic = get_model, R = 1000) 
boot_model$t0
boot_model
```

The error is the following:

> Error in t.star[r, ] <- res[[r]] :
> number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length

I tried to select the training dataset after the `mutate_at` but got the same error.

Comment: Please provide the output of `dput()` of your data as part of your question in order to reproduce the problem.